# Get parameters from node js from external website

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I tried to create a nodejs server which will return response of ip address value

```
app.get('/UserIP', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.connection.remoteAddress);
  res.send(JSON.stringify({'ip':req.connection.remoteAddress}));
});
```

later I have created a client to get this ip address

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON("http://localhost:7979/userip", function (data) {
                $('p').html('IP Address is: ' + res.ip);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I cant get that ip to my client website.there are websites like jsonip.com which are working with my code.
please help me in understanding where i m doing mistake.

Comment: Hi, have you tried to change localhost to any server?, also any errors or warnings?

Comment: "I cant get that ip to my client website." — What is the problem? Do you get a different result to the one you expect? Does an error message show in the console in the browser's developer tools? Does the Network tab in the browser's developer tools show something unexpected? Does the *server side* `console.log()` statement fire (i.e. is the request even being received)?

Comment: Routes are case-sensitive: you listen to `/UserIP`, but client sends request to `/userip`

Comment: I tried with server also and it also giving output {"ip":"10.11.111.251"} for server and localhost but my client is not getting output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I am not able to get json is due to permitions.To fix this we need to fix it write this code in apt.get

```
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

No other solution helped me.any way thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

- If you have `app.set('case sensitive routing', true);` in your app , 
  accessing "**/userip**" instead of "**/UserIP**" will not work. You have `app.get('/UserIP'` and `$.getJSON("http://localhost:7979/userip"`.
- In your jQuery code , you are accessing a "**res**" Object `+ res.ip)` , even
  though you are returning a "**data**" `function (data)` Object.